# Llenar un texfield a partir de un combobox en EXTJS6

Tags: php, sql, extjs

Me tocó continuar un proyecto y tengo unas dudas respecto a `EXTJS6`.

Sucede que quien trabajaba antes usaba Sencha Architech, el cual no sé usarlo muy bien por lo que los archivos los he estado viendo y entendiendo a mano, pero aun así me cuesta encontrar la relación entre ellos e implementar lo que les preguntaré a continuación.

Lo que quiero hacer es tomar un dato que aparece listado en un `combobox` que es cargado mediante una base de datos, y a partir de ese dato que seleccione quiero llenar un `textfield`.

Ejemplo: seleccionar Departamento de ingeniería, y que el textfield automáticamente llene Facultad de ingeniería (o la dirección donde pertenece). La consulta de la base de datos la tengo lista ya que hice la unión de tablas y todo pero la estructura o viaje de variables entre archivos no las tengo claras.

Según vi, se trabaja así:

Se tiene una vista que declara el aspecto y variables como listeners.
Luego va a un ViewController que contiene los métodos a aplicar de dichos listeners. Esto luego va ligado a un modelo con otras variables (no se muy bien como actúa). De ahí esta ligado a un `storage` que tiene variables que mediante ajax se pasan a un `php` que ejecuta la consulta `SQL` en la base de datos.

No sé si ese es el viaje de los datos, o realmente viajan de otra manera.

¿Alguien podría explicarme ese proceso?, y lo otro, si es posible algún ejemplo de llenar un textfield a partir de un combobox siguiendo esa estructura?.

Se lo agradeceré mucho

---

Introduzco el codigo del combobox y el texfield para mayor idea:

```
onUnidadSelect: function(combo, record, eOpts) {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=cmb_nuevoCC]')[0].setValue('');
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=cmb_nuevoSCC]')[0].setValue('');
    Ext.getStore('cc.sto_centroCosto').load({
        params:{unidad_codigo:record.data.unidad_codigo},
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {

        }
    });


    var cuenta_grid    = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().getCount();


    for (var i = 0; i < cuenta_grid-1; i++) {

        if (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.col_defecto == 'O' ){

            form_48.app.porcentaje_distrib = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.distribucion_codigo;

            var monto_origen = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.montos_int;
            var seleccionado = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().data.items[i];
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_centroCosto]')[0].getStore().remove(seleccionado);

        }
    }


    //SE RESTA PORCENTAJE DISTRIBUCION QUE SE ELIMINO
    var pocentaje_dist = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=txt_total_distribucion]')[0].getValue();

    var pocentaje_dist =  pocentaje_dist - form_48.app.porcentaje_distrib;

    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=txt_total_distribucion]')[0].setValue(pocentaje_dist);

    //SE RESTA EL MONTO QUE SE ELIMINO
    var monto_actual = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').miles_int(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=txt_total_monto]')[0].getValue());

    var monto_final = monto_actual - monto_origen;
    var monto_final_miles = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').int_miles(monto_final);

    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=txt_total_monto]')[0].setValue(monto_final_miles);




}
```

Su vista:

```
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                width: 408,
                fieldLabel: 'Unidad',
                labelWidth: 110,
                name: 'cmb_nuevoUnidad',
                readOnly: false,
                allowBlank: false,
                blankText: 'Campo obligatorio',
                emptyText: 'Seleccione...',
                displayField: 'unidad_nombre',
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: 'sto_unidades',
                valueField: 'unidad_codigo',
                listeners: {
                    select: 'onUnidadSelect'
                }
            }
```

Su store:

```
Ext.define('form_48.store.sto_unidades', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'form_48.model.mdl_unidades',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'sto_unidades',
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'form_48.model.mdl_unidades',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            extraParams: {
                combo: 'unidades'
            },
            url: 'json/seccion1.php',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'root'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

Ahora el Textfield

```
onFacultadKeyup: function(textfield, e, eOpts) {
    textfield.setValue(textfield.getValue().toUpperCase());
},
```

Su vista:

```
{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                fieldLabel: 'Dirección/Facultad',
                labelWidth: 110,
                name: 'txt_direccionFacultad',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup: 'onFacultadKeyup'
                }
            }
```

No sé si se deba hacer un store a el texfield o no, pero el store de Unidades conecta con el seccion1.php la que contiene la consulta SQL

Espero pueda ser mas claro ahi.

Comment: Si quieres ponerle al `textfield`el valor del combo, ¿por qué haces `textfield.setValue(textfield.getValue().toUpperCase());` ? Eso coge su propio valor y lo pasa a mayúsculas....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer es: rellenar un `textfield`en base a lo seleccionado en el `combobox`podrías hacerlo de la siguiente sencilla forma:

En primer lugar  vamos con la definición del combo:

```
tuCombobox = {
        xtype: "combobox",
        itemId: 'myId',
        fieldLabel:'etiqueta',
        queryMode: "local",
        store: myStore,
        displayField: 'LABEL',  //el valor a mostrar de cara al usuario
        valueField: 'VALUE', //el valor de los datos que manejarás
        listeners: {
            change: this.onUnidadSelect,
            scope: this
        }
    };
```

Ten en cuenta que todo `combobox`está asociado a un `store`el cual, a su vez, se asociado a un modelo de datos con los que los vas a cargar. Como verás, así le añadimos un ***[listener](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-listeners)*** y con `scope` le pasamos el contexto.

Ahora se define la función **onUnidadSelect** la cual recibirá el nuevo valor seleccionado en el combobox:

```
onUnidadSelect: function (combobox, newValue) {
    // ....
    Ext.getCmp('myId').setValue(newValue);
}
```

Dentro de esta función es donde puedes aplicar el nuevo valor del combo (*newValue*) al `textfield`que quieras con el método **[setValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-value)**. El cual previamente debes haber instanciado.

---

Aunque hubiera sido mucho más fácil, si pusieras la definición de tu `combobox` y la de tu `textfield` (por lo menos). No necesitamos (ni queremos o pretendemos) ver el código completo de toda tu aplicación, tan sólo, la parte de código que ejemplifica tu problema/duda/consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo un poco mas claro.

Mira, agregue el codigo para q puedas ver con mas claridad y quizas puedas guiarme mas exactamente en dicho codigo.
Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: No veo que dentro de la función `onUnidadSelect`  tengas ningún *setter* al propio `textfield` que quieres modificar su valor

Comment: Claro, por que no esta implementado, recien agregue el seteo al textfield, pero me esta devolviendo el codigo de la unidad en la base de datos:

var facultad_nombre = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=cmb_nuevoUnidad]')[0].getValue();
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=txt_direccionFacultad]')[0].setValue(facultad_nombre);

la idea es a a partir de ese codigo en la BD, lo utilize para buscar el nombre de la facultad en otra tabla mediante un join, pero segun veo el proyecto, esas consultas SQL las hicieron se llamabanpara llenar combos, no txtfield, no se como se haria

Comment: Hola amigo, tengo un inconveniente. como podria obtener el valor de un combobox que ya ha sido guardado, es decir, al mostrarlo en una venta, como podria hacer para obtener el valor? ya que si hago un getvalue me dice que no esta definido.